# Context Variable will not show up in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am writing a blog application, and a variable will not show up when the page is rendered. Here is my `views.py` function for my blog app:

```
def post_share(request, post_id):
    # retrieves post by id
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id, status='published')
    sent = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # FORM was submitted
        form = EmailPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # form fields passed validation
            cd = form.cleaned_data

            post_url = request.build_absolute_uri(post.get_absolute_url())                                          
            subject = '{} ({}) recommends you reading "{}"'.format(cd['name'], cd['email'], post.title)
            message = 'Read "{}" at {}\n\n{}\'s comments: {}'.format(post.title, post_url, cd['name'], cd['comments'])

            send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@myblog.com', [cd['to']])
            sent = True

    else:
        form = EmailPostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/share.html', {'post': post,
                                                'form': form,
                                                'sent': sent})
```

And `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment

class EmailPostForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    to = forms.EmailField()
    comments = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Relevant part of my HTML template:

```
{% block content %}
    {% if sent %}
        <h1> Email successfully sent </h1>
        <p>
            "{{ post.title }}" was successfully sent to {{ cd.to }} .
        </p>
    {% else %}
        <h1> Share "{{ post.title }}" by email</h1>
        <form action="." method="post">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="Send e-mail">
        </form>
    {% endif %}
```

The template loads and the email is sent but it only says:

> "Post Test" was succesfully sent to .

I need it to say the recipients email.

Comment: And where have you passed that variable into template? You've only passed `post`, `form` and `sent`. You didn't pass `cd`.

Comment: I tried this but obtained an error UnboundLocalError at /blog/1/share/
local variable 'cd' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the cleaned data in the template context. However, `cd` is only defined when the form is valid, so you can do something like:

```
data = {
    'post': post,
    'form': form,
    'sent': sent,
}

if sent:
    data['cd'] = cd
return render(request, 'blog/post/share.html', data)
```

Since you don't need the entire `cd` dictionary in the template, another option would be to pass only the variable you need, `cd['to']`.

```
data = {
    'post': post,
    'form': form,
    'sent': sent,
}

if sent:
    data['sent_to'] = cd['to']
return render(request, 'blog/post/share.html', data)
```

Then in your template, you would use {{ sent_to }} instead of {{ cd.to }}

Answer (score 0):

`cd` is only used within your view, but it is not a context variable.

To make it a context variable and accessible in the template you have to add it to your existing context variables:

```
return render(request, 'blog/post/share.html', {'post': post,
                                            'form': form,
                                            'sent': sent,
                                            'cd': cd})
```

Comment: I actually tried this, but it gives me an error.  UnboundLocalError at /blog/1/share/
local variable 'cd' referenced before assignment

Comment: You get this error because `cd` is not defined when `request.method != 'POST'`. Have a look at @Alasdair's answer for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `to` or `cd` to your context:

```
return render(request, 'blog/post/share.html', {'post': post,
                                                'form': form,
                                                'sent': sent})
```

For example:

```
{'cd': cd,
 'post': post,
 'form': form,
  'sent': sent}
```